# Intercept QMail SMTP emails

Tags: email, smtp, plesk, qmail

Here is the situation, we have a linux web server that runs Plesk and I need a way to intercept emails sent to and from the server. Plesk uses qmail to send and receive emails.

We have sorted the receiving emails problem by adding a mailgroup to each email address that includes an "archive@" address. Then we use a PHP script to read the "archive@" mailbox and puts the emails into a MySQL database.

My problem at the moment is how to capture the messages sent from the server. Has anyone had any experience in doing this?

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 1):

this can be done via QUEUE_EXTRA (http://www.google.com/search?q=queue_extra), for which you need to recompile qmail. some hints on doing this on plesk here (http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=pt&u=http://www.maglione.com.br/artigos/artigostecnicos/pleskqextrahowto).